# My JQuery equalTo is complaining that two similar emails do not match

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, jquery-validate

How come my matching of the two email addresses still claims they don't match even though they are exactly the same? It's email2 that get's the error message.

```
 * Email: <input type='text' name='email' /> <br/>
 * Repeat email: <input type='text' name='email2' /> <br/>   


$("#addagentform").live('blur',function(e){
                  $("#addagentform").validate({
                      rules: {  
                             email: {
                                required: true, 
                                email: true 


                              }, 
                              email2: {
                                    required: true, 
                                    equalTo: "#email"
                              },
                           }

                    }); 
 });
```

I've found other with the same problem, but appearently with different problems than I'm having since their solution didn't help me.

Comment: Not sure if this is it, but you are not assigning `id` properties to your fields. try `id="email"`

Comment: @Pekka, you should post a proper answer so I can give you points. "name" normally works but I guess it must be because "equalTo" refers to another element that ID should be used. A bit inconsequent I think but hey, now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning id properties to your fields. `#email` may not find a target this way.

Try

```
 <input type='text' name='email' id='email'/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping that in a `rules: {}` block, like so:

```
 * Email: <input type='text' id='email1' name='email1' /> <br/>
 * Repeat email: <input type='text' id='email2' name='email2' /> <br/>   


$("#addagentform").live('blur',function(e){
                  $("#addagentform").validate({ 
                         rules: {
                             email1: {
                                required: true, 
                                email: true 
                              }, 
                              email2: {
                                required: true, 
                                email: true,
                                equalTo: '#email1'
                              }
                           }
                    }); 
 });
```

Not sure if it *really* matters, but the convention is to use single quotes in rules, and field name `email` may not be valid, depending on which version of the plugin you're using. Try making the fields `email1` and `email2`. And finally, you should provide an `id` as well for the fields in question.

Comment: Sorry, I do but missed it when copying. Updated my post.

Comment: Well, it actually works but could of course be a problem in different browsers.